# Does the game auto-selects the tuning profile in NFSU2?

Tags: need-for-speed-underground-2

In ***Need for Speed Underground 2***, one can tune the car's characteristics. But upon entering the tuning screen, one needs to choose among several 'profiles', i.e., Circuit, Drag, Drift, StreetX, and URL.

My question: Does the game auto-selects which profile to use when entering a race? Or must I first go to, say the garage, and manually choose the profile to use prior to finding & entering a race?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Performance Tuning part of the game, you are only choosing which "profile" you are editing, not which one you are using; that is determined by which race you are in. I don't know which profile is used in the open-world portion of the game.

More about this feature can be read here: http://nfs.wikia.com/wiki/Dyno_Run

Comment: So, if I enter a race, say a URL one, it will automatically activate the "URL Race" profile?

Comment: That is correct